# Database design - Data feeds from multiple sources

Tags: sql, database-design, windows-server-2008, erd

Whats the best way to store the same type of data in the same table fed from multiple sorces?

My website table has multiple domains with one being facebook. Buisness rules state that one organisation can have multiple facebook addresses.

I was orignailly planning on deleting all website address with the domain of facebook for a organisation each time I got a new feed from one of my sources, but that would delete the other facebook websites loaded from the other sources.

What is the best way to over come this

Should I keep a record of the source where each record was loaded from in the table, or should I have seperate domain names depending on the load i.e. webfacebook, source1facebook.

Comment: its probably also worth pointing out that the web database isn't linked at all to the back end database. I'll be transfering data between them via SSIS

Comment: What does "source" mean to you? What does "feed" mean to you?

Comment: @Catcall, hi. Source would be the origins of the data ie. source of web data would be user input into the website. The other source would be a client company who are passing XML files containg data daily. The 3rd source would be excel spread sheets I'm asked to Jam in. A feed would be a automated process to load the data from each source.

Answer (score 1):

I would create say, as "Source" table used to identify the feeds in the, say, "Feeds" table....providing the feeds from the sources has common data (columns if you may). That way if you need to delete or update a feed for "facebook" then you can first fetch "facebook" feeds then drill into that...that's my 2 cents.